# check billing (and blobstore) enabled from app

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I was wondering if there was a way to check if billing/blobstore was available from within an app. I have tried to use the capabilities api for blobstore being enabled but it cannot tell if billing/blobstore is available.

Basically I want to know if the app place I'm delpoying to is setup for free or billing (and subsequently blobstore) from within a java app.

P.S. I have tried catching the exception com.google.apphosting.api.ApiProxy$FeatureNotEnabledException which appears to be thrown in app's logs but it does not catch it (or any exception), but simply shows a error page.

Thanks,
Steven

Comment: You should be able to catch the exception in question. Have you tried using a broader `catch` clause, then logging the exact class yourself?

Comment: I have catching Exception (not any particular). It seems to be occurring before entering any of code. I have not tried a top level filter yet, maybe I'll try that next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed by adding a filter which just tries to access the blobstore service in any way and catch exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

sorry, i don't believe there's currently any way to programmatically determine if the current app has enabled billing or not. the capabilities api is intended to handle when services are down for maintenance system-wide, not available per app.

the one thing you could try is programmatically authenticating to the admin console, using either ClientLogin or OAuth, and fetching its billing page.

Comment: hmm, maybe i should create some page that has a blobstore request and it is accessed once upon startup automatically and the result is stored for the app to query upon later? worst part is an error would be logged